# Filter groupby by combos with either category types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[[1,'A','X','1/2/22 12:00:00AM', 'Alpha'], 
[1,'A','X','1/3/22 12:00:00AM', 'Alpha'], 
[1,'A','X','1/1/22 12:00:00AM', 'Beta'], 
[1,'A','X','1/2/22 1:00:00AM', 'Gamma'], 
[1,'B','Y','1/1/22 1:00:00AM', 'Alpha'],
[2,'A','Z','1/2/22 12:00:00AM', 'Alpha'],
[2,'A','Z','1/1/22 12:00:00AM', 'Alpha'], 
[2,'A','Z','1/1/22 12:00:00AM', 'Beta'], 
columns=['ID', 'Category', 'Site', 'Task Completed', 'Type'])
```

| ID | Category | Site | Task Completed | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1/2/22 12:00:00AM | Alpha |
| 1 | A | X | 1/3/22 12:00:00AM | Alpha |
| 1 | A | X | 1/1/22 12:00:00AM | Beta |
| 1 | A | X | 1/2/22 1:00:00AM | Gamma |
| 1 | B | Y | 1/1/22 1:00:00AM | Alpha |
| 2 | A | Z | 1/2/22 12:00:00AM | Alpha |
| 2 | A | Z | 1/1/22 12:00:00AM | Alpha |
| 2 | A | Z | 1/1/22 12:00:00AM | Beta |

I want to find the ***Max - Min Task Completed date*** for all ID/Category/Site combos with type 'Alpha'. For the combo to be counted, they also need to have at least one other type besides 'Alpha'. I also want to count the instances of the 'Alphas' for the ID/Category/Site combos.

So, for this dataset, my intended result would look like this:

| ID | Category | Site | Time Difference | # of instances |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | A | Z | 1 | 2 |

I know how to get the counts and time difference if 'Type' is not considered:

```
# convert the "Task Completed" column to datetime:
df["Task Completed"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Task Completed"], dayfirst=False)


x = df.groupby(["ID", "Category", "Site"], as_index=False).agg(
    **{
        "Time Difference": (
            "Task Completed",
            lambda x: (x.max() - x.min()).days,
        ),
        "# of instances": ("Task Completed", "count"),
    }
)

print(x)
```

Which prints

```
   ID Category Site  Time Difference  # of instances
0   1        A    X                2               4
1   1        B    Y                0               1
2   2        A    Z                1               2
```

But I can't figure out how to consider 'type' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aaa = []

def my_func(x):
    ind = x['Type'] == 'Alpha'
    alf = x.loc[ind, 'Type'].count()
    if alf >= 2 and len(x[x['Type'] != 'Alpha']) != 0:
        difference = (x.loc[ind, 'Task Completed'].max() - x.loc[ind, 'Task Completed'].min()).days
        bbb = x[ind][['ID', 'Category', 'Site']].values[0]
        bbb = np.insert(bbb, 3, [difference, alf])
        aaa.append(bbb)



df.groupby(["ID", "Category", "Site"], as_index=False).apply(my_func)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(aaa, columns=['ID', 'Category', 'Site', 'Time Difference', '# of instances'])

print(df1)
```

Output

```
   ID Category Site  Time Difference  # of instances
0   1        A    X                1               2
1   2        A    Z                1               2
```

Made a function that I passed when grouping. The variable alf counts how many lines with 'Alpha' . If there are two or more rows with 'Alpha' and at least one row is not 'Alpha', then we read the data. The result is stored in the aaa list, which is inserted into a new dataframe.

**Update 08.12.2022**
Changed the dataframe now it has become:

```
   ID Category Site Case     Task Completed   Type
0   1        A    X  AAA  1/2/22 12:00:00AM  Alpha
1   1        A    X  AAA  1/3/22 12:00:00AM  Alpha
2   1        A    X  AAA  1/1/22 12:00:00AM   Beta
3   1        A    X  BBB   1/2/22 1:00:00AM  Gamma
4   1        A    X  AAA  1/4/22 12:00:00AM  Alpha
5   1        B    Y  BBB   1/1/22 1:00:00AM  Alpha
6   2        A    Z  FFF  1/2/22 12:00:00AM  Alpha
7   2        A    Z  FFF  1/1/22 12:00:00AM  Alpha
8   2        A    Z  FFF  1/1/22 12:00:00AM   Beta
```

Output

```
   ID Category Site Case  Time Difference  # of instances
0   1        A    X  AAA                2               3
1   2        A    Z  FFF                1               2
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', header=0)

df["Task Completed"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Task Completed"], dayfirst=False)

aaa = []

def my_func(x):
    ind = x['Type'] == 'Alpha'
    alf = x.loc[ind, 'Type'].count()
    if alf >= 2 and len(x[x['Type'] != 'Alpha']) != 0:
        difference = (x.loc[ind, 'Task Completed'].max() - x.loc[ind, 'Task Completed'].min()).days
        bbb = x[ind][['ID', 'Category', 'Site', 'Case']].values[0]
        bbb = np.insert(bbb, 4, [difference, alf])
        aaa.append(bbb)



df.groupby(['ID', 'Category', 'Site', 'Case'], as_index=False).apply(my_func)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(aaa, columns=['ID', 'Category', 'Site', 'Case', 'Time Difference', '# of instances'])

print(df1)
```

What changed:

1.In `groupby` added column 'Case'

2.In the `bbb` variable, a selection of a string from 'Case' has been added.

3.`np.insert(bbb, 4, [difference, alf])` instead of 3 we insert it into the fourth one.

4.Added 'Case' column when creating `df1`.

Comment: Hi! thanks again for your answer. If I wanted to add another field to this combo, how would I do it? For example, if I instead had ID, Category, Site, Case combination, how would I adjust the above code?

Comment: @CowboyCoder i did as much as I understood you. If not, an example is needed.